# Adding a section on a form in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a form in CRM 2011 with a tab split into 2 columns. On this tab, I want to add a section that spans across both columns of the tab (the entire width of the form). When I insert a section on the tab, it just adds the new section to the left column of the tab and I am unable to get it to span across the other column. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding a new one-column tab without showing the tab name below the existing tab and adding a one-column section within that tab. So this now ends up looking like another field within the same tab since the new tab doesnt have a name displayed. Thanks for your help Jason Lattimer!

Answer (score 3):

Insert a one column tab. Drag a field to one of the 2 columns inside the tab. Click on the field, then on Change Properties in the ribbon on the top of the page. Select the formatting tab and then choose 2 columns.

Comment: I have fixed this issue by adding a new one-column tab without showing the tab name below the existing tab and adding a one-column section within that tab. So this now ends up looking like another field within the same tab since the new tab doesnt have a name displayed. Thanks for your help Jason Lattimer!